# Some missing pixels (grey) after duplicating a picture

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Currently I face the problem that some pixels are disappearing when I duplicate a picture. They are replaced with just grey pixels.

[image]

I really have no idea why this happens. It looks like just some green ones are missing, but I was not able to find something about this problem.
The normal should look like that:

[image]

It's not the only picture. It's the same with other pictures. Has someone an idea what maybe could cause this, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Are you copying it from a browser?  Also it might be a gamut warning.

Comment: If I take a picture from the browser it's ok. But if I dublicate the picture in Photoshop then the pixels are missing.

Comment: Thats not what i asked really, i asked if you copy images from browswer as in right click copy. Or using save as... Because these produce different kinds of files as clipboards dont support all features. But thats moot as we have established its a gamut warning.

Comment: Ahh sorry, no I use save as and not copy. Yes it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost certainly this looks like the Gamut Warning in Photoshop. To fix it, simply uncheck it: `View` > `Gamut Warning` and make sure the option is unchecked.

[image: Screenshot of Gamut Warning]

It might be pertinent to note that the Gamut Warning, even when enabled has no effect on the actual image. On export your image will look normal. The Gamut Warning exists to show out of gamut pixels when converting an RGB image to CMYK.  If you are not doing that, then there is no reason to have it on at all.

Comment: Well not quite. You could also have gamut warning in wide RGB format to sRGB conversion. So not only for CMYK

Comment: Been looking for this answer everywhere! Thank you so much