# Sky shows block red in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have some raw photos taken using the Automated Exposure Bracketing setting on my drone camera.

They look fine in microsoft photos but when I open them in Photoshop Camera Raw part of the sky is bright red.

Any ideas why?

[image]

Comment: Probably it is showing the Gamut Warning. Shift+Ctrl+Y.

Comment: Which I was also going to post as a comment, but then thought better of :P

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Some missing pixels (grey) after duplicating a picture](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/90830/some-missing-pixels-grey-after-duplicating-a-picture)

Answer (score 2):

They are areas of over-exposure.

You seem to have the Gamut Warning on, if you are bracketing to later HDR, then you can probably switch it off & ignore it.

In Photoshop itself -  View menu, or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>Y</kbd>  [swap  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  for  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  is on Windows]

Inside Camera RAW it's just the  <kbd>O</kbd>  key, Mac or Windows.

Comment: thanks -- In camera raw it's just the "o" key on windows.

Comment: Ah, yes, it's different in Camera Raw to Ps itself, oddly. Will update answer.